# Comparison between signed and unsigned. Is static_cast the only solution?

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, static-cast

I use third party containers that use `int` to store the size. I also use stl containers which use `size_t` to store size.

I very often in my code have to use both in the same loop, like for example:

```
// vec is std::vector
// list is the third party container
assert(vec.size() == list.size()); // warning
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    vec[i] = list[i]; // warning
}
```

So to fix I have to either I do function style casting, which I was told is C style casting in disguise.

```
// vec is std::vector
// list is the third party container
assert(int(vec.size()) == list.size());
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    vec[i] = list[int(i)];
}
```

Or I can do the even uglier solution that everyone recommends. The static casting.

```
// vec is std::vector
// list is the third party container
assert(static_cast<int>(vec.size()) == list.size());
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    vec[i] = list[static_cast<int>(i)];
}
```

I really don't want to `static_cast`.

- Can the implicit conversion in this particular scenario be dangerous?
- Would the function style be okay in my case?
- If static_cast is really the only safe solution. Should I cast the `int` to `size_t` or `size_t` to `int`?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no functional difference between static_cast and C-style cast in your example, they both do the same thing. The advice to not use static_cast comes from the fact that it is a bad muscle memory, and that explicit cast makes it easier to understand the code. As for direction of the cast, what is allowed range of `size_t` vs `int` on your platform?

Comment: @SergeyA sizeof(int) = 4. sizeof(size_t) = 8

Comment: @serg also because if size returns a pointer or a type convertible to pointer, c-style could get you an int cast from pointer reinterpret.  Unlikely here?  Yes.  Does it happen?  Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary operators (`operator==` here) convert signed integers to unsigned if one of the arguments is unsigned. A signed negative integer turns into a big positive one.

Container element count must not be negative to avoid breaking the principle of least surprise. So, the implicit conversion must be safe. But be sure to check the implementation/documentation of `int size() const`.

You may like to preserve the semantics of the implicit conversion and use `as_unsigned` function to avoid the cast and better convey the intent:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
inline typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type as_unsigned(T a) {
    return static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(a);
}
```

and then:

```
assert(vec.size() == as_unsigned(list.size()));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that function still give a warning?

Comment: @AdamZahran Nope.

Comment: Okay so it won't give a warning with -Wall but it does with -Wsign-conversion. Should I just not care or disable/suppress it?

Comment: I honestly hate that I worry about these small details. Like I know for a fact that the `int size() const` will never return a negative. I looked into the code and I can't see how it can go wrong. I think I'll just disable some warnings and be careful. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Okay wait. If we do `inline unsigned as_unsigned(int a) { return static_cast<unsigned>(a); }` it'll just work! :D without warnings too. I think I'll go with that.

Comment: @AdamZahran `as_unsigned` compiles without a warning with no cast. Try it.

Comment: It does give a warning with `-Wsign-conversion` https://godbolt.org/z/p6ivY_
at least that's the case with g++

Comment: @AdamZahran I see. I use `-Wall -Wextra` and `-Wsign-conversion` is not there. Updated the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. Is the `inline` keyword useless now that we've made it a function template?

Comment: I would tend to just disable the warning for the scope of the `as_unsigned` function body, instead of casting.  Casts are powerful and can do undesired things.  By removing the cast, you allow the compiler to check that an implicit conversion exists.

Comment: @AdamZahran `inline` is not necessary for a function template, you are right.

Comment: @BenVoigt Disabling the warning just for the function requires using pragmas. Whereas this implementation relies on `std::make_unsigned` template, which also disables the template if `std::make_unsigned<T>::type` is not defined for `T`.